# Java Spark Framwework Application calling From Jframe Button Click

Tags: java, maven, jframe, spark-java

Hi Guys I have two seperate applications. One is in JFrame Desktop Application, Other one is in maven sparkjava framework web app.I want to call this maven web application to be launched on the button click of JFrame desktop application.
Desktop Application is collecting the data and creating the database.Web application is accessing this database and visualise the data.
Seperately both of the application are working fine

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: @ Christophe Willemsen  "neo4j" tag is just for the information that the database is in neo4j.